# How to remove some part of start, end of TeeChart

Tags: c#, winforms, teechart

I am working with windows form application in c#. I have installed licensed version of TeeChart for.net v3. I am trying to remove some unwanted portion of TeeChart.
Thanks to stackoverflow website users, they helped me to create a mouse click popup on TeeChart. Now i want to implement some functionality for that popup clicks.
using the below code i am able to create mouse right click popup.

```
double m_dblTempVolFromTo = 0;
double dtFromTo = 0;
private void mainTChart_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!checkBoxIsTime.Checked && e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        m_dblTempVolFromTo = mainTChart.Series[0].XScreenToValue(e.X);
        mainTChart.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("From " + m_dblTempVolFromTo + " cc"));
        mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("To " + m_dblTempVolFromTo + " cc"));
        mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].Click += new EventHandler(From_Click);
        mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems[1].Click += new EventHandler(To_Click);

    }
    else if (checkBoxIsTime.Checked && e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        dtFromTo = mainTChart.Series[0].XScreenToValue(e.X);
        DateTime.TryParse(dtFromTo.ToString(), out dt);
        mainTChart.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("From " + dt.TimeOfDay.ToString() ));
        mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("To " + dt.TimeOfDay.ToString()));
        mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].Click += new EventHandler(From_Click);
        mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems[1].Click += new EventHandler(To_Click);
    }

}
```

The above code is creating popup like as shown below.
[image]
I am trying to implement functionality for "For 7.6 cc" and "To 7.6 cc".
when i click "To 7.6 cc" then the chart should remove from "0 to 7.6" scale and remaining part should be there. As well the same apply for "From 145 cc" click, it has to remove the chart from "145 to 150(end of scale)".
click on "To" is using to remove starting portion of chart and click on "From" is using to remove end portion of chart.
I have tried like this but i am not able to get what i want.

```
void From_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!checkBoxIsTime.Checked)
    {
        var destBitmap = mainTChart.Export.Image.Bitmap.Clone(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 200), sourceBitmap.PixelFormat);
    }
}

void To_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

even i have tried with this code also

```
void mainTChart_GetLegendRect(object sender, mainTChart.GetLegendRectEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle cropRect = e.Rectangle;
    Bitmap legendImg = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(legendImg))
    {
      g.DrawImage(chartBmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, mainTChart.Width, mainTChart.Height),
                 cropRect,
                 GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
}
```

nothing is working for me. Can any one help me with this task.

Thanks in advance.

> Edited
>   when i have X-axis as time then i am not able to get display time on mouse click. The code I have tried as shown below

```
 DateTime dt;
        dtFromTo = mainTChart.Series[0].XScreenToValue(e.X);
        DateTime.TryParse(dtFromTo.ToString(), out dt);
        mainTChart.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("From " + dt.TimeOfDay.ToString() ));
        mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("To " + dt.TimeOfDay.ToString()));
```

I am getting like this 
[image]
I am getting as shown in the above image but want to display the equivalent time on mouse right click. I am getting some value to this variable "dtFromTo" like 41322.9876587965" but i am not able to convert that value into time. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known the values you want to "cut" From/To, you can just set the Bottom axis Minimum and Maximum properties.

> when i click "To 7.6 cc" then the chart should remove from "0 to 7.6"
>   scale and remaining part should be there

This would be:

```
mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.AutomaticMinimum = false;
mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.Minimum = 7.6;
```

> As well the same apply for "From 145 cc" click, it has to remove the
>   chart from "145 to 150(end of scale)".

This would be done setting the Maximum:

```
mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.AutomaticMaximum = false;
mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.Maximum = 145;
```

So I think this should to the trick:

```
    void From_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.AutomaticMaximum = false;
        mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.Maximum = m_dblTempVolFromTo;
    }

    void To_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.AutomaticMinimum = false;
        mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.Minimum = m_dblTempVolFromTo;
    }
```

I'd also suggest you to create the `ContextMenu` in `mainTChart_MouseDown` event insted of `mainTChart_MouseUp` because creating it at the `mainTChart_MouseUp` event is too late, the ContextMenu shown won't show the updated version.

**Edit:**

For DateTime XValues, the wrong line is this one:

```
DateTime.TryParse(dtFromTo.ToString(), out dt);
```

Here it is the full code that seems to work fine for me here:

```
    private void InitializeChart()
    {
        mainTChart.Aspect.View3D = false;

        Line line1 = new Line(mainTChart.Chart);
        line1.XValues.DateTime = true;
        line1.FillSampleValues();
        mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.Labels.DateTimeFormat = "hh:mm";

        mainTChart.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(mainTChart_MouseDown);
    }

    double m_dblTempVolFromTo = 0;
    double dtFromTo = 0;

    void mainTChart_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.IsDateTime && e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            m_dblTempVolFromTo = mainTChart[0].XScreenToValue(e.X);
            mainTChart.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("From " + m_dblTempVolFromTo + " cc"));
            mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("To " + m_dblTempVolFromTo + " cc"));
            mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].Click += new EventHandler(From_Click);
            mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems[1].Click += new EventHandler(To_Click);

        }
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            dtFromTo = mainTChart[0].XScreenToValue(e.X);
            String stFromTo = mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.Labels.LabelValue(dtFromTo);
            mainTChart.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("From " + stFromTo));
            mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("To " + stFromTo));
            mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].Click += new EventHandler(From_Click);
            mainTChart.ContextMenu.MenuItems[1].Click += new EventHandler(To_Click);
        }
    }

    void From_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.AutomaticMaximum = false;
        if (!mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.IsDateTime)
            mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.Maximum = m_dblTempVolFromTo;
        else
            mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.Maximum = dtFromTo;
    }

    void To_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.AutomaticMinimum = false;
        if (!mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.IsDateTime)
            mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.Minimum = m_dblTempVolFromTo;
        else
            mainTChart.Axes.Bottom.Minimum = dtFromTo;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help it is working perfectly, But I have one more small doubt which I have added one more function to popup that is "Reset". When i click "Reset" it has to perform undo operation. can you help me with that please.

Comment: can you give some idea how to implement "reset" functionality.

Comment: thanks for your answer now i have implemented "reset" also based on your idea. thanks alot

Comment: you can add a third `MenuItem` for the Reset (Reset_Click) and set both Bottom Axis `AutomaticMinimum` and `AutomaticMaximum` properties to true.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have small problem, sorry for asking once again and i don't want to post this issue as another question. I am asking you, please try to help me. In the above code I have X-axis as one is volume another one is Time. I am getting X-axis value exactly when volume is there using this line "m_dblTempVolFromTo = mainTChart.Series[0].XScreenToValue(e.X);" but when i have Time as x-axis I have tried the same procedure but the time is displaying "00:00:00" always. I am some values using above code but i am not able to display that value in time.Do have any idea about it.